# What kind of encryption or packing method is used for the provided JavaScript code?

Tags: encryption

I have placed the packed/encrypted JavaScript code presented below in an html in between script tags:

```
console.log(function(p, a, c, k, e, d) {
while (c--) {
    if (k[c]) {
        p = p.replace(new RegExp("\\b" + c + "\\b", "g"), k[c]);
    }
}
return p;
}("23(16=(15='࠵ϾĹà{࢙Јà࠵Į26ࢤԩçòè࠾Ӑ࢚ϩƤ{⟭Ԫèþ⟬Љçú~✥Ԫðþ⟭ϪƛÝÓࡀӆóÌ࠾ӆƺÓࡊӆĮþࡀҼŃł⟭ϵƛÜÒࢭӆçþ⟭ϴêú~⟭Ԫêý⟭ϾƛÍÓࡉϴƒÖ{ࡉһèþË⟤ьƒú×⟢юçá⟬ҲƚõÒ⟘ӄĶýÉ⟬ҳƚôÎࢣӄêÌ⟢ӐƒÊ{⫺ϩçþéࡀӆçþ⟭јñú~⟭Ԫêþ⟭љƛÓࢤϼƒÖ{࠿Ԫçü࢙ϫóĮÊ࠾ӆƺÓࢮӆĺÊÌࡈѠƺÓ✛ӆðþ⟭їĬú࠿ӅŘü࠶юçþ}⟢ҼƒĮÌࡉһéþ{⟭эƛÕ⟚ϳƛÞÓ✚ӆðþ⟚ϼƚÓࢮӆĮþ~⟭ϴƛ×ÎࢭӐƤĮËࡈӅêþ{⟭їƛÌ⟢ӐƒÊ|⫺ϩçþ}⟢ϳƛÌ✑ϪèÉÓࡊҼƤĮË⟤юƔÔÒ࠾ӆêþ⟭ϫƛÎࢮӅéý⟬эƔÔÒࡉӆńþ⟭ϴƛÓÓ✚ӆôþ⟭ЉƛÜÎࢮӆéþ⟭ЈƔÓÓ✐ӆçü⟭ьƛÊÓࢤӆŊþ⟭яƛÔÎࢮӅéý⟬ѡƚÜÎࢮӆĬþ⟭ѡƔÓÓࢢӆĺþ⟢ҼƤúÈ⭧ϲƤ7ࡈϾéĮ1ࡈѠƺÓࢮӆķþ⟭ЉĭúÓࡀҼĸ⟚Ϫƛ×Ì⟢Ͼƹ×࠶Ϫƛł}⟭ЉƛÞÓࢬЇƒ8}✚Ϫƹ').11,13=2,10='',9=0;9<16;9++)10+=14.27(24(15[9].25(0),!9||9%5?++13:13=3,21(18).11,(19(){20 22.28,40,48,46.44(49),43.45 47 42,41,33,14().32().31(),29 30,34,35.11,39,38,37})()));36(10)", 10, 50, "|z|||e||B|xz|x|i|s|length|g|d|String|uN|len|zz|false|function|return|uneval|Number|for|parseInt|charCodeAt|xy|fromCharCode|isInteger|typeof|Date|toUpperCase|toLowerCase|NaN|RegExp|Array|eval|true|undefined|null|Error|Boolean|File|Folder|ceil|Desktop|Math|instanceof|Object|Infinity".split("|")));
```

and when analyzed it in the Firefox console it outputs:

```
for(len=(uN='࠵ϾĹà{࢙Јà��࠵Į�xyࢤԩçòè࠾Ӑ���࢚ϩƤ�{⟭Ԫèþ�⟬Љçú~✥Ԫðþ�⟭ϪƛÝÓࡀӆó�Ì࠾ӆƺ�ÓࡊӆĮþ�ࡀҼŃł�⟭ϵƛÜÒࢭӆçþ�⟭ϴêú~⟭Ԫêý�⟭ϾƛÍÓæúÌ⫺ӐƤ8}✚Ϫƹ').11,13=2,10='',9=0;9<16;9++)10+=14.27(24(15[9].25(0),!9||9%5?++13:13=3,21(18).11,(19(){20 22.28,40,48,46.44(49),43.45 47 42,41,33,14().32().31(),29 30,34,35.11,39,38,37})()));36(10)", 10, 50, "|z|||e||B|xz|x|i|s|length|g|d|String|uN|len|zz|false|function|return|uneval|Number|for|parseInt|charCodeAt|xy|fromCharCode|isInteger|typeof|Date|toUpperCase|toLowerCase|NaN|RegExp|Array|eval|true|undefined|null|Error|Boolean|File|Folder|ceil|Desktop|Math|instanceof|Object|Infinity".split("|")));
```

I have changed eval(function(p, a, c, k, e, d) to console.log(function(p, a, c, k, e, d) so the code can be unpacked(decrypted?), but all I see is a next puzzle.
I have tried various unpackers and deobfuscators for the second piece of code but without success.
Will someone point me of what packing/encryption is used for the provided code?

P.S. The encrypted code is too, so I have included only a part of it with the readable content at the beginning and the end.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the custom function(p,a,c,k,e,d) used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21423397/what-is-the-custom-functionp-a-c-k-e-d-used-for)

Comment: I am afraid not. As I can understand, he explains the packer, and not packe(d) which uses Base62 encoding which this is not the case, it is something different. I get UTF-8 characters (0x99,0x8f etc). Is it something related to UTF encryption or am I speaking nonsense?

Comment: By analyzing the unpacked code I have the conclusion that it is packed by using various base systems, but I do not have a clue how to start to untie it. If someone can give me directions on how to start reversing it, what to look for etc. Thanks