# Scraping data generated by obfuscated JS code from website with rust

Tags: rust

I'm scraping website with a rust tool: [scraper](https://docs.rs/scraper/0.12.0/scraper/) for learning purpose, and plan to export it to node module with [neon-bindings](https://github.com/neon-bindings/neon).

When I scraping for list of url of images which load on the website, I notice there's a "packed" function in the script tag

```
eval(function(p, a, c, k, e, d) {
    ...
}(...))
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21423397/what-is-the-custom-functionp-a-c-k-e-d-used-for) answer I learn that this is a function which decompresses obfuscated JS code.

So I use [this](https://www.strictly-software.com/unpacker/) tool to unpack the code, and I get this:

```
var newImgs = [
    'http://manhua1034-104-250-139-219.cdnmanhua.net/1/432/1039483/1_8773.jpg?cid=1039483&key=d4366ee77be6255eeba85878cf442bbe&type=1',
    'http://manhua1034-104-250-139-219.cdnmanhua.net/1/432/1039483/2_2594.jpg?cid=1039483&key=d4366ee77be6255eeba85878cf442bbe&type=1',
    'http://manhua1034-104-250-139-219.cdnmanhua.net/1/432/1039483/3_9540.jpg?cid=1039483&key=d4366ee77be6255eeba85878cf442bbe&type=1',
    'http://manhua1034-104-250-139-219.cdnmanhua.net/1/432/1039483/4_1324.jpg?cid=1039483&key=d4366ee77be6255eeba85878cf442bbe&type=1',
    'http://manhua1034-104-250-139-219.cdnmanhua.net/1/432/1039483/5_1520.jpg?cid=1039483&key=d4366ee77be6255eeba85878cf442bbe&type=1',
    'http://manhua1034-104-250-139-219.cdnmanhua.net/1/432/1039483/6_3015.jpg?cid=1039483&key=d4366ee77be6255eeba85878cf442bbe&type=1',
    'http://manhua1034-104-250-139-219.cdnmanhua.net/1/432/1039483/7_6748.jpg?cid=1039483&key=d4366ee77be6255eeba85878cf442bbe&type=1',
    'http://manhua1034-104-250-139-219.cdnmanhua.net/1/432/1039483/8_4063.jpg?cid=1039483&key=d4366ee77be6255eeba85878cf442bbe&type=1',
    'http://manhua1034-104-250-139-219.cdnmanhua.net/1/432/1039483/9_1616.jpg?cid=1039483&key=d4366ee77be6255eeba85878cf442bbe&type=1',
    'http://manhua1034-104-250-139-219.cdnmanhua.net/1/432/1039483/10_2885.jpg?cid=1039483&key=d4366ee77be6255eeba85878cf442bbe&type=1',
    'http://manhua1034-104-250-139-219.cdnmanhua.net/1/432/1039483/11_6712.jpg?cid=1039483&key=d4366ee77be6255eeba85878cf442bbe&type=1',
    'http://manhua1034-104-250-139-219.cdnmanhua.net/1/432/1039483/12_4984.jpg?cid=1039483&key=d4366ee77be6255eeba85878cf442bbe&type=1',
    'http://manhua1034-104-250-139-219.cdnmanhua.net/1/432/1039483/13_5132.jpg?cid=1039483&key=d4366ee77be6255eeba85878cf442bbe&type=1',
    'http://manhua1034-104-250-139-219.cdnmanhua.net/1/432/1039483/14_4691.jpg?cid=1039483&key=d4366ee77be6255eeba85878cf442bbe&type=1',
    'http://manhua1034-104-250-139-219.cdnmanhua.net/1/432/1039483/15_9655.jpg?cid=1039483&key=d4366ee77be6255eeba85878cf442bbe&type=1'
]
```

Which contain exactly the data I wanted, but I have no idea how to get it in rust.

Is there any method to getting the data from obfuscated JS code in rust?

The page I plan to do web scraping: http://m.dm5.com/m1039483/

Comment: Doesn't seem like it. As a last resort you can call [JS code from Rust](https://rust-by-example-ext.com/webassembly/nodejshelper.html), thought you know it's not fast, but should be suitable for scraping

Comment: If the decompression function isn't too complex, you could try reimplementing it in Rust?

Comment: @AlexLarionov actually it's maybe a good idea for my case if there's no other choice, but the example you provided if I not mistaken it looks like a library similar to neon binding, since I already using neon binding, I'm not sure it is suitable for my case or not

Comment: @eggyal the decompression function is actually quite complex for me, this is the reason why currently I'm looking for alternative solution if possible

Comment: @jialeko the main problem with implementing a crate for it is that you can't really unpack the file unless you know the library/algorithm that packed it. And unfortunately there are many libraries... You're lucky to even discovering which exact algorithm was used for this particular web-site