# What is the Alternatives to eval in JavaScript? how to convert code using a eval() to using Function()?

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy

I am getting a security error for the eval(). an error looks likes below.

> Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because
> 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following
> Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'
> 'sha256-P/4RbWZ5tavHlZH3S2JukJ4toJ9iLwFkiBGYsngpgqo='
> 'sha256-i4JIH9RhDp81FOGH3ZwoQRt2R4uvOYyeOmkCZoX6HeY='
> 'sha256-3VlFnxIhSKloUaebh7I+Yjnu9vwMuwGEuqykqBQQLNw='
> 'sha256-GHjvsztQyqr0koa6RWaeYUhRgrR/WcXa+NGlCwEpcLY='
> 'sha256-3W2JH/z3DpHtF9okrA6TIFaJ6wFrL4gfTXfK5fjo1V0='
> ssl.google-analytics.com

Below is my JS code.

```
eval(function (p, a, c, k, e, r) {
    e = function (c) {
        return (c < a ? '' : e(parseInt(c / a))) + ((c = c % a) > 35 ? String.fromCharCode(c + 29) : c.toString(36))
    };
    if (!''.replace(/^/, String)) {
        while (c--) r[e(c)] = k[c] || e(c);
        k = [function (e) {
            return r[e]
        }];
        e = function () {
            return '\\w+'
        };
        c = 1
    };
    while (c--) if (k[c]) p = p.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + e(c) + '\\b', 'g'), k[c]);
    return p
}('3(7.X){7["R"+a]=a;7["z"+a]=6(){7["R"+a](7.1k)};7.X("1e",7["z"+a])}E{7.19("z",a,15)}2 j=H V();6 a(){2 e=q.1d("1a");3(e){o(e,"P");2 N=B(q,"*","14");3((e.12<=10)||(N=="")){c(e,"P",d)}}4=B(q,"*","1n");k(i=0;i<4.b;i++){3(4[i].F=="1g"||4[i].F=="1f"||4[i].F=="1c"){4[i].1b=6(){r();c(v.5.5,"f",d)};4[i].O=6(){r();c(v.5.5,"f",d)};j.D(j.b,0,4[i])}E{4[i].O=6(){r();c(v.5.5,"f",d)};4[i].18=6(){o(v.5.5,"f")}}}2 C=17.16.13();2 A=q.M("11");3(C.K("J")+1){c(A[0],"J",d)}3(C.K("I")+1){c(A[0],"I",d)}}6 r(){k(2 i=0;i<j.b;i++){o(j[i].5.5,"f")}}6 B(m,y,w){2 x=(y=="*"&&m.Y)?m.Y:m.M(y);2 G=H V();w=w.1m(/\\-/g,"\\\\-");2 L=H 1l("(^|\\\\s)"+w+"(\\\\s|$)");2 n;k(2 i=0;i<x.b;i++){n=x[i];3(L.1j(n.8)){G.1i(n)}}1h(G)}6 o(p,T){3(p.8){2 h=p.8.Z(" ");2 U=T.t();k(2 i=0;i<h.b;i++){3(h[i].t()==U){h.D(i,1);i--}}p.8=h.S(" ")}}6 c(l,u,Q){3(l.8){2 9=l.8.Z(" ");3(Q){2 W=u.t();k(2 i=0;i<9.b;i++){3(9[i].t()==W){9.D(i,1);i--}}}9[9.b]=u;l.8=9.S(" ")}E{l.8=u}}', 62, 86, '||var|if|elements|parentNode|function|window|className|_16|initialize|length|addClassName|true|_1|highlighted||_10||el_array|for|_13|_6|_c|removeClassName|_e|document|safari_reset||toUpperCase|_14|this|_8|_9|_7|load|_4|getElementsByClassName|_3|splice|else|type|_a|new|firefox|safari|indexOf|_b|getElementsByTagName|_2|onfocus|no_guidelines|_15|event_load|join|_f|_11|Array|_17|attachEvent|all|split|450|body|offsetWidth|toLowerCase|guidelines|false|userAgent|navigator|onblur|addEventListener|main_body|onclick|file|getElementById|onload|radio|checkbox|return|push|test|event|RegExp|replace|element'.split('|'), 0, {}))
```

I am not much familiar with JS and CSP errors. can anyone help me with how to change this eval function?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: `Below is my JS code.` what does it do?

Comment: This looks like obfuscated packed code so why would you want to convert it?

Comment: *"...how to convert code using a eval() to using Function()?"* That's only very marginally safer than `eval`. Any tool complaining about `eval` will likely complain about `new Function`.

Comment: More context is needed here. Consider checking [this issue](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/issues/713) for possible workarounds.

Comment: Why is this tagged HTML and PHP? Even jQuery seems irrelevant.

Comment: if you want to allow your JS code to run on your website, simply update your *Content Security Policy directive* to include `unsafe-eval` - or don't obfuscate your code in the first place

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - jQuery has been irrelevant for years :p

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks. but is it secure to add `unsafe-eval`? because I have checked in CSP document it is showing it is dangerous to use eval.

Comment: So remove your packing and your eval will disappear

Comment: @ChiragPatel - I suggested two alternatives - it's not like that code is anything that requires obfuscating! I'm reading it now and I'm thinking, why did you bother trying to obfuscate that code?

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks, do you mean that this error is showing due to a packed file. there is no error in the code right?
I have unpacked my js using this http://matthewfl.com/unPacker.html and js code looks totally different.
can you provide some more information related to this packaging js? why we use it? is it required to pack? any documentation can you share so can review it.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=packed+OR+packer+javascript+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158869/javascript-packer-versus-minifier

Comment: ESPECIALLY THIS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24680035/295783

Comment: Thanks to all :)